# how to create method to validate user input between a certain range

Tags: c#, validation, methods

I have to create a method where i have 3 parameters a String prompt, int min, int max. How do i create a method where i ask the user a to pick a number between a certain range. Convert the user input to a int, and validate if its in the range of min and max. Also if user does not put a number between range keep asking question until its in range.

```
   public int ReadInteger(string prompt, int min, int max) {
            Console.WriteLine(prompt);
            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            int number;
            bool conversion = int.TryParse(userInput, out number);
            
            while (conversion) {
                bool result;
                if (number < min || number > max) {
                    result = false;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(prompt);
                
                
                
            }
            return number;
            
        }
```

Comment: inside the while loop, after the Console.WriteLine, you'd want to call Console.ReadLine() and do `conversion = int.TryParse(userInput, out number);` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything needs to be repeated in the case of invalid input:

```
public int ReadInteger(string prompt, int min, int max)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(userInput, out int number) && number >= min && number <= max)
        {
            return number;
        }
    }
}
```

`while(true)` will repeat indefinitely until a valid integer has been input.